# why does my leopard gecko bite me?

Tags: behavior, aggression, biting, leopard-geckos

My leopard Gecko tends to bite me.

He hasn't shed yet. I'm worry about him/her. He's kinda mad at me all the time. I give him his crickets, food, water and he will scream at me. He does have water, food, rocks, etc... Very spoiled boy...

I'm just trying too be a good mum/dad. I got him from pet smart. Please help me.

Comment: This needs more information ideally. How old is he? What are you doing when he tried to bite you/scream at you? Also, he might have shed, they eat it so it's possible you'll never see it.

Comment: i don't really know how old he is hes about 4 half inches. he screams at me when i feed him his crickets! Hes been at his water tank often lately but that may be because its warm right now... e bites me when i try to pick him up. i let him know i'm there and he sees me too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the additional info you provided, I'd say that it's just because he's young. When they're small and young they're quite defensive and will scream/lunge at you, especially if you try touch them. He should grow out of it.

To get him used to your hand though, don't just go straight for him and pick him up. Every day, leave your hand in his enclosure for around 10 minutes. When he starts approaching/climbing on your hand, you can start picking him up. Even when he's comfortable however don't pick him up from above.

Answer (score 0):

In general, small animals are very aware that they are prey, and are likely to be skittish until they are pretty darned convinced that the big critter isn't going to eat them. Patience, moving slowly, and whenever possible giving them the choice of whether to interact or not goes a long way toward establishing you as mostly harmless.